# NLog timestamp accuracy

Tags: .net, nlog

This is a timestamp i get from NLog

> 16:03:39.5813

Ive read online discussions on weather the accuracy should and can be milliseconds or 16ms increments but the timestamp after the dot seems to count up to 10.000! 
What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.DateTime has the ability for sub-millisecond precision (0.0001 ms):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks

NLog shows an extra decimal incase the machine has enabled high-resolution timers. It is similar to using this format-strimg: `HH:mm:ss.ffff`

https://blog.machinezoo.com/how-to-configure-nlog-time-source

http://caraulean.com/2016/timestamp-accuracy-and-resolution-in-nlog/

But usually the default time-resolution of DateTime.UtcNow is 1-16 ms.